# php fails to load file, cannot seem to find error

Tags: php, file-upload

I am adding a file upload function to my php page. The code seems correct to me and it even adds the file to the server with the correct name, but with no contents. i.e. there is an empty .jpg file when loading an image.

Can any of you more experienced php developers see what I am doing wrong to produce empty files.

calling script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mediaFileInput").on("change", function(e){
                console
                if (e.target.value) {
                    var formData = new FormData(e.target.form);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'media.php',  //Server script to process data
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                            location.reload();
                        },
                        // Form data
                        data: formData,
                        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });   
                }
            });
        });           
    </script>
```

media.php

```
<?php
   require('config/config.php');

    $file_uploaded;
    $mime_type;

    // Handle multipart file uploads
    if (isset ( $_FILES ['file'] )) {
        $file_uploaded = fopen($_FILES['file']['name'], "r");
        $mime_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    } else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        /* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
        $file_uploaded = fopen("php://input", "r");

        /* Open a file for writing */
        $mime_type = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
    }

    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $new_path = "media/" . $file_name;
    $media_url = "/" . $new_path;
    $fp = fopen($new_path, "w");

    /* Read the data 1 KB at a time
       and write to the file */
    while ($data = fread($file_uploaded, 1024)) {
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    }

    /* Close the streams */
    fclose($fp);
    fclose($file_uploaded);
    chmod($new_path, 0755);

    // insert into database.
    $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MEDIA (type, url) VALUES(?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', 
       $mime_type, 
        $media_url);
    $stmt->execute();
    $media_id = $db_conn->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();

    echo json_encode(array("id" => $media_id, "type" => $mime_type, "url" => $media_url));


    ?>
```

Comment: Why do you do a location.reload() in the success.  Then you might as well just submit the form regularly and not use ajax at all

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `fopen("php://input", "r");` because according to the [docs for it](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

When you're uploading a file, of course, you have to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. So instead, use [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Also, `fopen($_FILES['file']['name'], "r");` in your other branch doesn't make sense, since that's just trying to open a filename with no particular path. Use move_uploaded_file.

Comment: I am a little confused. I added the "move_uploaded_file", but I am certain that that was not the only thing you were talking about.

Can you be a little more specific?